# List all ancestors of a child in hierarchical data structure

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

Consider the following sample table:

```
with v1 as (
select 'I' as parent_id, 'M' as child_id from dual union all
select 'M', 'M1' from dual union all
select 'M', 'D' from dual union all
select 'I', 'P' from dual union all
select 'P', 'K' from dual union all
select 'A', 'P1' from dual union all
select 'C', 'A' from dual union all
select 'A', 'I' from dual union all
select 'P1', 'K1' from dual
)
select ListAgg(child_id,'<-')
   within group(order by Level desc)  as Path
from v1
START WITH child_id = 'D'
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = child_id;
```

It returns:

```
A<-I<-M<-D
```

It is not returning A's parent which is C.

What should I change in the query so that it returns C as well like below:

```
C<-A<-I<-M<-D
```

NOTE that before executing the query, I have no means to know that C is the root of the hierarchy. So, I can not pass C in the query (and that is how I have designed the my query above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
With v1 as (
select 'C' as parent_id, 'A' as child_id from dual union all
select 'I', 'M' from dual union all
select 'M', 'M1' from dual union all
select 'M', 'D' from dual union all
select 'I', 'P' from dual union all
select 'P', 'K' from dual union all
select 'A', 'P1' from dual union all
select 'A', 'I' from dual union all
select 'P1', 'K1' from dual
)
select ListAgg(case when level =1 then parent_id || '<-' || child_id else parent_id end,'<-')
   within group(order by Level desc) as Path
from v1
START WITH child_id = 'D'
CONNECT BY prior parent_id = child_id;
```

[Sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e420d/10)

Cheers!!